# jquery focus on an input using keydown

Tags: jquery, input, focus

If an input is unfocused, how to focus on it just by hitting the enter key.(theres no button or anything else involved. just one input.)

For example something like:

```
$(!("input").focus().keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $("#input").focus();
    }
});
```

Edit:
Went with ehsan's approach, slightly modified:

```
if(e.which == 13 && $(document.activeElement).not("#user-input")) {
    $("#user-input").focus();
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you did not have the typo in your code. You should be listening to the window for keypress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

**Html:**

```
 <input type="text" class="inputFocus">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on("keypress",function(e){

    if(e.which==13 && !$(":focus").hasClass("inputFocus")) 
        $(".inputFocus").focus();

})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    
   <input type="text" class="inputFocus">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    
    $(document).on("keypress",function(e){

        if(e.which==13 && !$(":focus").hasClass("inputFocus")) 
            $(".inputFocus").focus();

    })
    
       
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#input").focus();
    }
});
```

you can disable this for `<textarea>`:

```
$("textarea").keydown(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: he is looking for a solution which checks whether the input is not already focused you are doing it without checking it "If an input is unfocused"

Comment: @Tomas I see nowhere where the OP says that.

Comment: read the topic : If an input is unfocused, how to focus on it just by hitting the enter key.(theres no button or anything else involved. just one input.)

For example something like:

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/24m729nx/

```
let input = document.querySelector("input");
let idInput = document.querySelector("#input");

input.addEventListener("focus",function(){


    this.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){

    let keycode = e.keyCode;
    if(keycode = 13){

        idInput.focus();

    }

  });



});
```